# Make outline in Excel OpenXML

Tags: c#, xml, excel, ms-office, openxml

I'm adding rows to a spreadsheet using OfficeOpenXml row copy method, Every time I add a row, I set the outlinelevel of the row (olLevel incremented outside of loop below). I'm testing with 12 total rows, attempting to place in two groups of six.

```
for (int j = 0; j < employeeRecordCount; j++) {
detailRow.Copy(outputSheet.Cells[detailRowStart + j, columnA]);
outputSheet.Row(detailRowStart + j).OutlineLevel = olLevel;
startingRow++;
lastdetailRow++;}
```

When I open the spreadsheet, all rows are in one group of 12 and the last six rows are grouped but nested within the larger group (the six collapse/expand independently of all 12). If I repeat 6 of the records from my input file, those records are grouped together as 12 and the other 6 are nested.

I know I'm forgetting to set something besides outlinelevel to keep the groups seperate from each other but I cannot figure it out.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that every detail row began with a header row. Excel was grouping all the rows on one level and creating another nested level to group rows under the next unique header row.

I edited the code to not apply an outline level to the first detail record (header row) and the rows are no longer nested.

Comment: So mark this as answer and add the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Relevant code snippet is far removed from snippet above. I'm looping through a list of employees, and added a row each loop before the snippet above begins.